# Equivalent of rtrim with StringBuilder in java

Tags: java, string, replace, stringbuilder

I am trying to trim `StringBuilder` from right side, something like this :

```
private StringBuilder rtrim(StringBuilder str, Character trimStr) {
    if (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == trimStr) {
        return str.deleteCharAt(str.length() - 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

The above function works fine with character as trimStr, but I want to pass trimStr as string. Any library for the same(similar to StringUtils)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use replaceAll or just replaceFirst with regex like so :

```
String str = "  some string  ";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s*$", "");//output is "  some string"
```

---

Edit

If you are using StringBuilder you can use :

```
private static StringBuilder rtrim(StringBuilder str, String trimStr) {
    return new StringBuilder(
            str.toString().replaceFirst("(" + Pattern.quote(trimStr) + ")+$", "")
    );
}
```

Some inputs and outputs

```
"  some string   "    + " "    ==> "  some string"
"  some stringaaa"    + "a"    ==> "  some string"
"  some stringabab"   + "ab"   ==> "  some string"
```

---

### left trim (lTrim)

For left trim you can just change your regex to be `str.toString().replaceFirst("^(" + Pattern.quote(trimStr) + ")+", "")`

```
private static StringBuilder rtrim(StringBuilder str, String trimStr) {
    return new StringBuilder(
            str.toString().replaceFirst("^(" + Pattern.quote(trimStr) + ")+", "")
    );
}
```

---

Another Solution without regex

#### right trim (rTrim)

```
public StringBuilder rTrim(StringBuilder str, String trimStr) {
    if (str != null && trimStr != null) {
        int trimLen = trimStr.length();
        int strLen = str.length();
        if (strLen != 0 && trimLen != 0) {
            while (strLen != 0 && str.substring(strLen - trimLen, strLen).equals(trimStr)) {
                str = str.delete(strLen - trimLen, strLen);
                strLen = str.length();
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

#### left trim (lTrim)

```
public StringBuilder lTrim(StringBuilder str, String trimStr) {
    if (str != null && trimStr != null) {
        int len = trimStr.length();
        if (str.length() != 0 && len != 0) {
            while (str.length() != 0 && str.substring(0, len).equals(trimStr)) {
                str = str.delete(0, len);
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I am using StringBuilder!

Comment: While this answer works it creates three new byte arrays(toString, replaceFirst and constructor of StringBuilder) with a length around the same as the one of `str.length()`. Imo this partially defeats the purpose of using a StringBuilder at all, which is why i downvoted.

Comment: Thank you @Riiverside for the explanation but does the OP talk about performance In his question ?

Comment: @Riiverside also generally I don't like to judge other's solution but did you check your solution with this `rtrim(new StringBuilder("  some stringaaaa"), "a")` it will return wrong information no?

Comment: He does not, but if there is a solution with better performance(at least memory wise, cpu might depend on the input) why not use it? If the call is done only a few times it does not matter much, but if it is called thousands of times, it might. Using the information provided by OP one can't tell how many times it is called, so I prefer a more efficient solution.

Comment: The Answer I posted simply removes `trimStr` once. This is analogous to the method provided in the question. I updated my answer and added a method that removes all occurrences of `trimStr` at the end of the StringBuilder

Comment: @Riiverside ok I edit my answer with another solution without replaceFirst or regex, I think it is more performance than the first one

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
private StringBuilder rtrim(StringBuilder str, String trimStr) {
    if(str.length() == 0 || trimStr.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    int lastIndexOf = str.lastIndexOf(trimStr);

    if(lastIndexOf >= 0 && lastIndexOf + trimStr.length() == str.length()) {
        str.setLength(lastIndexOf);
    }
    return str;
}
```

This will remove `trimStr` from the end of the provided `str`.
Using `lastIndexOf` directly on the `StringBuilder` avoids converting everything to a string.

If you want to remove all occurrences of `trimStr` at the end of `str` you can do something like this:

```
private StringBuilder rtrim(StringBuilder str, String trimStr) {
    if(str.length() == 0 || trimStr.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    int lastIndexOf;
    while((lastIndexOf = str.lastIndexOf(trimStr)) >= 0 && lastIndexOf + trimStr.length() == str.length()) {
        str.setLength(lastIndexOf);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, you can use Apache `StringUtils` library :

```
private static StringBuilder rTrim(StringBuilder sb, String stripChars) {
    return new StringBuilder(StringUtils.stripEnd(sb.toString(), stripChars));
}

private static StringBuilder lTrim(StringBuilder sb, String stripChars) {
    return new StringBuilder(StringUtils.stripStart(sb.toString(), stripChars));
}
```